# Sort by specific column in vba

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

Hello i need some help to Sort some data in EXCEL using VBA. I have this code

```
Dim keyRange As Range
Set strDataRange = Range("A1:AB300")
Set keyRange = Range("W1")
strDataRange.Sort Key1:=keyRange, Header:=xlYes
```

The idea is sort all the data in the range `A1:AB300` by the data in the column W. The issue is the code is just doing the sort to the column W, is not sorting the rest of the columns.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Try like this, including the whole range to the `keyRange` and refering the worksheet:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim keyRange        As Range
    Dim strDataRange    As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set strDataRange = .Range("A1:AB300")
        Set keyRange = .Range("W1:W300")
        strDataRange.Sort Key1:=keyRange, Header:=xlYes
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub sort()

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1:Z" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("W1:W" & LastRow), _
   Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

PS. There are loads of examples of sorting in net.